# Is it possible to pattern match on scala's akka ByteString?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka

I'm implementing a self-defined TCP protocol with [akka's tcp extention](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/io.html)

Adopting the SimplisticHandler in tcp server example [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/io-tcp.html#Accepting_connections)

```
class SimplisticHandler extends Actor {
  import Tcp._
  def receive = {
    case Received(data) => sender() ! Write(data)
    case PeerClosed     => context stop self
  }
}
```

Under `Received(data)`, is it possible to pattern match on the Byte sequence? As I understand it, there need to be an extractor defined in order for the pattern matching to work. There seems to be no `unapply` defined as per the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.7/#akka.util.ByteString).

I want something like:

```
def receive = {
    case Received(data) =>
        val worker = getSomeWorkerActor
        worker ! data
  }
```

Then in children workers:

```
private[this] def commandA(cmd: ByteString) = println(cmd)
def receive = {
    // [warn] foo.scala:55: abstract type pattern Coll is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    // [error] foo.scala:55: type mismatch;
    // [error]  found   : scala.collection.SeqLike[T,Coll]
    // [error]  required: akka.util.ByteString
    case 0x01 +: command => commandA(command)  
    case 0x02 +: 0x03 +: command => commandB(command)
}
```

while keeping `command` as `ByteString`. If so how? Or what would be a recommended alternative? 
I want to avoid decoding into String then compare against string if that's possible.

scala 2.11.8, akka 2.4.7

Comment: Are you just trying to match on the first byte?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Ideally would be matching to arbitrarily number of bytes

Comment: It seems to work out of the box if you use this: `case 0x01 +: command => …`.

Comment: @devkat Oh indeed it does, but then it spit out warning as `abstract type pattern Coll is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`. I guess that's another question. Can you advice on how one can deduce such operator can be used in pattern matching from the [doc](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.7/index.html#akka.util.ByteString@+:[B>:A,That](elem:B)(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]):That)? I would probably never figure it out by reading the doc alone

Comment: Strange, I don't get the warning, does it occur directly in the match pattern? Regarding the pattern matching, this is an infix operation match, analogous to lists, see http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#infix-operation-patterns.

Comment: @devkat You are right. Your suggestion work perfectly for matching against `data` in parent actor. Apology for not reflecting my use case precisely. `data` is sent to children actor for further processing and the warning/error within child actor's receive method. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a pattern matching construct, the type of the pattern is not infered from the right-hand side of the case clause, see also [Pattern Matching Expressions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-expressions). Therefore the parameter type of `commandA` and `commandB` is not considered. You have to match on ByteString first:

```scala
def receive = {
  case b: ByteString => b match {
    case 0x01 +: command => commandA(command)  
    case 0x02 +: 0x03 +: command => commandB(command)
  }
}
```